# Laravel tinker not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am facing a weird issue, Its quite simple, I am finding the first user in `User` model :

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\next-gen>php artisan tinker
  Psy Shell v0.7.2 (PHP 7.0.6 ΓÇö cli) by Justin Hileman                                                                  >>>                 

  $user=App\User::first()

    `[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]                                                                 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '1' (T_LNUMBER), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)`
```

The above error comes up, With other models the following method works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue in my `User` Model, I was passing the raw values in parameters.

Thanks